# Can we always approximate (by below) any continuous function by smooth functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in C\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$ be a continuous function.
Does always exist a sequence of smooth functions $f_{j}\in C^{\infty}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$
such that $f_{j}\left(x\right)\leq f\left(x\right)$ for any $x\in\left[0,1\right]$
and $f_{j}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\left[0,1\right]?$

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Pick $g_n=f-\frac1n$, and consider polynomials $f_n$ such that $\lVert f_n-g_n\rVert_\infty\le\frac1{5n}$. Forcibly, $\frac4{5n}\le f-f_n\le\frac6{5n}$.