# Dense subset of function space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

During my master program the following question raised: consider the space of continous functions with $\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$. This is a normed space when equipped with the infinity norm.

Let fix a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $F$ be the subset of functions that avoid $y$ (this is, such that $y$ is not in the image of $f$). Is that set dense? Is it open? I think the answer to both questions is yes, but I am not sure about how to justify it. Do I need to find a sequence of functions that uniformly converge to any arbitrary function $f$ of the space? I don't know much about function spaces, so I don't really know how to proceed.
Thanks!

Edit: feel free to correct the tags, in case any of them is incorrect.
Edit: I think I have proved that the space is open. I still don't know how to prove that it is dense.

Comment: I think you want $\mathbb R^3,$ not $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: @zhw Yes, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is actually not much topology at play here. You should be able to solve your problem using standard tools from differential geometry.

Here is an outline:

**Fact 1**: Continuous functions can be uniformly approximated with smooth ones.

**Fact 2**: By [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), if $S$ is a surface and $f:S \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth map, the range of $f$ has dense complement.

**Corollary of Fact 2**: There exist arbitrarily small vectors $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x \mapsto f(x)+a : S \to \mathbb{R}^3$ does not have a given point $y$ in its range.

There is a slightly annoying detail here because you are dealing with a manifold with boundary and you may not find this case covered in standard references. A cheap way around this issue would be to extend your original continuous function a bit so it is defined on an open manifold instead (Tietze extension theorem works here) and then restrict back at the very end.

Comment: Could you please explain the corollary and how it is obtained? I don't get it to be honest

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: The point is that $b$ is in the range of $f$ if and only if $y$ is in the range of $f+y-b$. So you just pick vectors $b \approx y$ which aren't in the range of $f$ and put $a=y-b$.

Comment: @MikeF Could anything like this here work: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077218/can-we-always-approximate-by-below-any-continuous-function-by-smooth-functions  adjusting for multidimensionality?

Comment: @MikeF Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any more elementary analyitic methods? I know absolutely nothing about differential geometry. I don't want to seem ungrateful, I found your answer really helpful, but I don't really have the background to understand it, i'm afraid.

Comment: @Vivianne: using polynomial approximations is a good idea. You could also try some kind of piecewise linear construction. You might be happier with the fact the range of a piecewise linear map is "small" (because it's a union of finitely many pieces of planes, which have zero measure). The point is to somehow replace the original map (which could be some kind of wild [space filling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) ) with a well-behaved approximation. Intuitively, the image of a map from a 2d object to a 3d object should miss most points, unless the map is very wild.

Comment: @MikeF I will keep thinking about it. Could you recommend me some standard reference in the topic? Thank you again for all your help

Comment: I think if you really want an elementary approach, your best bet will be to try for some kind of piecewise linear approximation argument. Think of a continuous function $\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ as a continuous function $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(0,y)=f(1,y)$ for all $y \in [0,1]$. Then, chop $[0,1]^2$ into very small triangles and replace $f$ with the continuous function $g$ which agrees with $f$ on the vertices of each triangle but whose restriction to each triangle is an affine map.

Comment: Since $f$ is uniformly continuous you can show that, by choosing the triangles small enough, the resulting map $g$ can be made to have $\|f-g\|_\infty$ as small as desired. Now the range of $g$ is a finite union of 2-dimensional, closed triangles and it follows from this that the complement of the range of $g$ is dense (check that a finite intersection of dense, open sets is still dense and open). If $y$ happens to be in the range of $g$, you can just translate $g$ by some tiny amount to fix that problem, as explained in my response to JustDroppedIn's question. Does that help you?